# What's needed here for the ajax server response to be executed as-is in the jQuery ajax post function?

Tags: ajax, jquery

The jQuery function below returns this string:

```
'#prayer_date'.html("03/19/1968");
```

But it doesn't get executed because the function below doesn't act on the `data` variable.

What would you need to do to have the result above executed as-is in the function below?

```
$('.showprayer').click( function(event) 
{
  $.post('/show_prayer', { 'name' : $(this).text() }, function(data) 
  {
      // how to execute the `data` server response as-is?
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response would need to be valid script first, like this:

```
$('#prayer_date').html("03/19/1968");
```

Then in your function you can call [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), like this:

```
$('.showprayer').click( function(event) {
  $.post('/show_prayer', { 'name' : $(this).text() }, function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

....**but this is almost never a good solution**, there's probably a better/more direct route to do what you're after.  A slightly better/safer solution is to use the expanded [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) form for a global eval, like this:

```
$('.showprayer').click( function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/show_prayer',
    type: 'POST',
    data { 'name' : $(this).text() }, 
    dataType: 'script'
  });
});
```

The difference is that this uses [`jQuery.globalEval()`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/core.js#L566) which sticks the script in the `<head>` as if it were a normal GET requested `<script>`, instead of actually calling [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) on it.