# Is there much significance in the choice of $.ajax() over $.post()?

Tags: jquery

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008676/whats-needed-here-for-the-ajax-server-response-to-be-executed-as-is-in-the-jquer/4008685#4008685), it is better to use the `$.ajax()` function:

```
$('.showprayer').click( function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/show_prayer',
    type: 'POST',
    data { 'name' : $(this).text() }, 
    dataType: 'script'
  });
});
```

rather than the `$.post()` function:

```
$('.showprayer').click( function(event) {
  $.post('/show_prayer', { 'name' : $(this).text() }, function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

The reason given is:

```
The difference is that this uses `jQuery.globalEval()` which sticks the script 
in the <head> as if it were a normal GET requested <script>, instead of actually 
calling `eval()` on it.
```

**My question is, if this is correct, why is it important for the script to end up in the ? Does that make a big difference over using eval()?**

Comment: Well, that question is addressing the concept of your ajax returning *javascript* (as opposed to ordinary JSON) -- the response of the ajax call is javascript containing jQuery code, etc.  IMO that's a terrible way of using AJAX.  If you're returning normal JSON then this topic is moot and you should use whichever one is more convenient for you.

Comment: your question has context of `script` regarding the validity of each of those types of usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in your examples has nothing to do really between .post() and .ajax(), it's just about built-in JS eval() vs. jQuery.globalEval().  These differences are covered here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/

but they don't do a great job of explaining why it matters.  Here's the issue: if you do just do an ordinary eval of a line like:

```
 var foo = 5;
```

from inside a .post() call, that "foo" variable will only live inside that call.  If you later do anything else on that page, that variable will be gone, because it was scoped to the anonymous that you passed in to your "post".  In contrast, the jQuery "globalEval" method will make that foo variable a property of window, ie. it will be in the global scope.  This means that any other function you subsequently run will still have access to it.

(Side Note:  Putting lots of variables in the global scope isn't actually always a good idea, because of potential naming conflicts, so the globalEval isn't *always* better.)

In any case, you don't have to stop using post to get the benefits of your returned script's variables being global.  Just do:

```
$.globalEval(data);
```

in your post function instead of "eval" and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, `$.post()` is indeed just a shorthand to `$.ajax`.

The specialty in the question you link to and Nick's answer is the fact that the OP wants to execute Javascript code directly. There is a `dataType` parameter just for that:

```
dataType: 'script'
```

this parameter cannot be specified in `$.post`, only in `$.ajax`. Setting this parameter causes the returned data to be evaluated by jQuery's [`globalEval()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) function, which executes the JS code in the global context and not in the context of the `success` callback.

See docs on `dataType` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax gives you a bit flexibility, you can choose POST or GET and you can leave $.post in current case

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the post, which isn't really about post vs. ajax, it's about the built-in jQuery function (globalEval) that gets run as a side effect of the way he used ajax (and because of that function, there is a significant difference between post and ajax in this case).

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` give better control and flexibility over the params while `$.post`, `$.get` are just shorthands